# How to implement a SelectList

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectlist

Looking for an example showing how to implement a SelectList control on a Visualforce page using an **extension** class.

I am able to display the selectList, but I am not sure how to **save** the value to the object, and then display it back on a detail page.

I used this page (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm) as a reference to get this far.

This is the extension class for my Opportunity_New visualforce page for creating a new Oppotunity. This is used to pre-populate some fields on the record.

```
public with sharing class OpportunityNewExtension 
{ 
    Public Opportunity opp {get; set;}
    Public Opportunity oppy;


     public OpportunityNewExtension(ApexPages.StandardController sc)
    {       
        Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        oppy=(opportunity)sc.getRecord();

        Map<String,String> m = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
        Account acc = [select id,
                              name,
                              CEI_Customer_Number__c,
                              Sales_Account_Manager__c,
                              Customer_Service_Rep__c 
                       from Account 
                       where ID=:(Id) m.get('accid')];

        //system.debug(acc);

        // default in values for a new record
        oppy.AccountId = acc.id;
        oppy.cei_Customer_Number__c = acc.cei_Customer_Number__c;
        oppy.Sales_Account_Manager__c = acc.Sales_Account_Manager__c;
        oppy.Customer_Service_Rep__c = acc.Customer_Service_Rep__c;
        oppy.CloseDate = Date.today() + 300 ;
        oppy.StageName = 'Quoting';
        oppy.Probability = 0;

        //system.debug(Oppy);
    }     

    public PageReference save()
    {        
        //oppy.U_O_M__c =  'TEST VALUE 001';
        opp=oppy;   

        Upsert opp;
        return new PageReference('/' + opp.id); 
    }
}
```

This is the second extension class I want to add to the visualforce page.

```
public class Lookups
{
    public string unitOfMeasure{get;set;}

    ApexPages.StandardController sc; 

    public Lookups(ApexPages.StandardController sc)    
    { 
        this.sc = sc; 
    }

    public PageReference test()
    {        
        return null;
    }



    public List<SelectOption> getItems()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        options.add(new SelectOption('FT','FT'));        
        options.add(new SelectOption('IN','IN'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('KG','KG')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('LBS','LBS'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('M','M'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('MIMP','MIMP'));             
        options.add(new SelectOption('MM','MM'));

        return options;
    }

    public String getUnitOfMeasure()
    {
        return unitOfMeasure;
    }

    public void setUnitOfMeasure(String unitOfMeasure)
    {
        this.unitOfMeasure= unitOfMeasure;
    }
}
```

This is my visualforce page

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="OpportunityNewExtension,Lookups" >
    <apex:sectionHeader title="{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.label} Edit" subtitle="New {!$ObjectType.Opportunity.name}"/>
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.label} Edit" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="Account" columns="2">
            <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.AccountId}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Sales_Account_Manager__c}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.cei_Customer_Number__c}"/>
         <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Customer_Service_Rep__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="Opportunity" columns="2">
            <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.ForecastCategoryName}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}"/>            
            <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Probability}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Status__c}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
            <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.CloseDate}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="true" title="Opportunity - Sales" columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Name}"/> 
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Class__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Type}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.PD_Engineer__c}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Division__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Market_Group__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Market__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Submarket__c}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.TotalOpportunityQuantity}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Unit_of_Measure__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Amount}"/>


            <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.U_O_M__c}"/>


            <apex:selectList value="{!unitOfMeasure}" multiselect="false" Size="1" rendered="true">   
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>  
            </apex:selectList> <p/>  



            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Commercialization_Date_Orig_Est__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Commercialization_Date_Curr_Est__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Est_12_Mo_Revenue_at_Commercialization__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Est_Margin__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Est_12_Mo_Margin_Improvement__c}"/>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem />
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Outcome_Status__c}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Outcome_Status_Reason__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" title="Description Information" columns="2">
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" title="Additional Information" columns="2">
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" title="System Information" columns="2">
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2">
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Tim -- if I understand you correctly, you have a one extension class that holds the value of the selection but you want that value to be saved in a separate extension class.  If yes, one way to do this is to have both classes extend a super class or use static class objects with each registering themselves to that super (or static) class. Then, class 1 can reference public variables/methods in class 2 (and vice-versa) . That said, a sharable select list could also be implemented using a custom VF component and custom controller (and again, the controllers have references to each other.

Comment: see see https://adtennant.co.uk/blog/2014/03/20/component-controller-communication-using-interfaces-part-1/ and http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13444/multiple-controller-extensions-communication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one Apex class and use this class as controller with visualforce page and create new buttton that will call to Save method and save the record. In this example I have used Account object to save the value. Once it is saved you can display in any page. hope this helps.

**Controller**

```
public Class ClassName{
  public string str{get;set;}
  public pagereference Save(){
   //Here set the str value with object`s field.
   //like you  want to create new account with selected value.
   Account act = new Account(name=str);
  insert act;
  return null;
 }
}
```

**your VF Page:**

```
<apex:page  controller="ClassName">
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
    This is your new Page: OptionPicker
    <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <apex:form >
    <apex:selectList id="recent" size="1" >
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!changeRt}" reRender="recentmodify">
    </apex:actionSupport>
      <apex:selectoption itemLabel="option1" itemValue="card">
    </apex:selectoption>
      <apex:selectoption itemLabel="option2" itemValue="check">
    </apex:selectoption>
      <apex:selectoption itemLabel="option3" itemValue="Scholarship">
    </apex:selectoption>
  </apex:selectList>
    <apex:commandbutton value="Save selected value!" action="{!Save}"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I am a SF newbie and am not able to understand your method for this. Why do I have to create a new Save button? Why can't I use the one that is already there? Does this mean I need two Save buttons?

Comment: @Tim I have just given an example showing how it works. You can use your existing Save button. Can you please post some of your code so that I can help you further.

Comment: I have added my code to the original question. I have added the relevant code from the Lookups class to the OpportunityNewExtension class and removed the extension reference from the vf page.  I am able to save the value from the SelectList. Howver, it is our goal to separate the selectlist out so that we can use the selectlist in many different locations.