# Communicating between Controller classes

Tags: apex

We have two vf page and two controllers. What is the best way to allow these classes to share data between each other.

Example:

```
public class A {
    public static DateTime dt{get;set;}
    public  CSC_CommuncationController() {
        dt = system.now();            
    }    
}

public class B{
    public static DateTime dt{get;set;}
    public B() {
    system.debug('**'+A.dt);
    }
}
```

debug returns the blank value. can any one help on this.
Note: We cant merge into single class as per requirement.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Controller_Component_Communication

Comment: Best way to do that what Eric given as an answer but you can also check following discussion http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13444/multiple-controller-extensions-communication

Comment: The reason it's blank is because you are never setting it. If you want to instantiate `A.dt` statically, you need to use a `static` block. If you want it to be stateful, you should remove the `static` keyword. You are mixing the two approaches and your intent is therefore unclear.

Answer (score 2):

There's several ways you can communicate across controllers. This depends on if you're using a [`StandardController`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm) or not. If you're using just a normal controller and extension, then the two can naturally communicate with each other:

```
public class A {
    public DateTime dt { get; set; }
    public A() {
        dt = DateTime.now();
    }
}
public class B {
    A aController;
    public B(A controller) {
        aController = controller;
        System.debug(controller.dt);
    }
}
```

If you are using a standard controller, you cannot guarantee the order of instantiation. Generally, this means you'll need to make use of static variables and an after-construction action method. That might look like this:

```
public class A {
    public static A self;
    B other;
    public A(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        self = this;
    }
    public void updateControllerRefs() {
        B.other = A.self;
        other = B.self;
    }
}
public class B {
    public static B self;
    public static A other;
    public B(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        self = this;
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter which class you put the function in, but it needs to be called after all constructors, like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="A,B" action="{!updateControllerRefs}">
```

Once the references are assigned, they will maintain their values for the entire duration of the page's life cycle.

You can also communicate through a common component, like this:

```
public class A {
    public static A aController { get; set; }
    public C comp;
    public A(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        aController = this;
    }
}
public class B {
    public static B bController { get; set; }
    public C comp;
    public B(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        bController = this;
    }
}
public class C {
    public A refToA;
    public B refToB;
    public void setARef(A obj) {
        refToA = obj;
        refToA.comp = this;
    }
    public void setBRef(B obj) {
        refToB = obj;
        refToB.comp = this;
    }
}
```

Which would require a component like this:

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:attribute name="refToA" assignTo="{!aRef}" type="A" description="Reference to A" />
    <apex:attribute name="refToB" assignTo="{!bRef}" type="B" description="Reference to B" />
</apex:component>
```

Which also requires you include the component on the page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="A,B">
    <c:commonBridge refToA="{!aController}" refToB="{!bController}" />
```

Note that A and B cannot communicate with each other during the constructor phase. They may only reference each other in action methods or getters/setters that are called after all constructors have been executed.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, Thank you so much for your help but our problem is here:  We have one parent page, on parent page we have have 72 page links. Each page will have own extension. Parent page is standard controller of (parent object) and all child pages are standard controller of (child object).  The parent page variables want it on the child pages. Please help me on this.

Comment: The parent page variables in the form of wrapper class. We cant even pass it on url.

Comment: @ShravanBoddula I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve, but you'll probably need to use components instead of pages.

Comment: shouldn't the custom component line 1 be: `<apex:component controller="C">` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since your DateTime field is static when you call `obj.dt` this is return null because before storing any values in variable you are trying to access.

Below is the example if you call B class then you will able to get `system.now()` value in debug

```
public class A {
    public DateTime dt{get;set;}
    public  A() {
        dt = system.now();            
    }    
}
```

--

```
public class B{
    public static DateTime dt{get;set;}
    public B() {
        A obj = new A();
    system.debug('**'+obj.dt);
    }
}
```