# Pass value from one VF component controller to another VF component controller within same VF page without side-effects

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, custom-controller

I wonder how to pass value from one VF component to another VF component within same VF page. I think that Passing VF Page controller to component and set it as parentController in component Apex Controller its not the best solution for that.
According to [Controller Component Communication](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Controller_Component_Communication) article I need to use side effects - not recommended because getter or setter can be called multiple times.
I wonder if exists better approach for that problem?

Comment: No, you don't need to use "side effects." I think you're misunderstanding the intent.

Comment: I know that approach is for passing data from VF component to VF page but how to pass values between components within same VF page?

Comment: Pretty much the same deal; if both components have a common variable to use (e.g. the page extension), they can communicate with each other. See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/100332) and [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/13447), and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sfdcfox. I have a component with notification messages and I want simply call a method from another VF component controller to addMessage to display on my notification messages component. It will be great if I can access notification messages component controller on construction phase, because I fetch records from REST API. I wonder if it is possible?

Comment: Additionally is that approach (from first link that you provide @sfdcfox): `public void setARef(A obj) {
        refToA = obj;
        refToA.comp = this;
    }
    public void setBRef(B obj) {
        refToB = obj;
        refToB.comp = this;
    }` example of side effect or I can use it without any worries?

Comment: Yeah, side effects you need to worry about are trying to DML or SOQL or SOSL in a getter method. As long as you avoid that, you should be okay.

Comment: Ok. I got it. Thanks a lot for help @sfdcfox.